Combining tangentially related datasets into one table
I've trying to combine two datasets into one easy-to-digest format.
As an example of what my ask is, let's say I run an animal breeding agency.
First, a listing of animal breeders, the name of the animals sold, how much the animal sold for and where the pet resides:



Breeder
Animal Name
Pet Sales
Pet Home




Robert
Dog 1
$1300
Los Angeles


Robert
Dog 2
$1200
San Francisco


Brendan
Dog 3
$3120
Chicago


Jacob
Dog 4
$5340
Houston



Second, a listing of breeders who are agreeing to breed more pets, their contract number, where the pets will be sent to, and the date they need to breed the pet by:



Breeder
Adoption Contract
Pet Home
Breed-by Date




Robert
AB 1
Los Angeles
9/24/2025


Robert
AB 2
San Diego
9/24/2025


Brendan
AB 3
Cincinatti
1/4/2025


Brendan
AB 3
Cincinatti
1/4/2026


Lisa
AB 4
Miami
5/2/2025


Lisa
AB 5
Honolulu
5/2/2025


Lisa
AB 5
Honolulu
5/2/2026


Kim
AB 6
Juneau
8/2/2025



I want to find a way to get these two tables into one condensed form (like a PivotTable) that depicts all breeders who have already sold pets, which city their pets are located and their average sales in that area. On top of that, I want this table to also show their adoption contract if they have one, the location where they're pledging to send their adoption, and their breed-by date.
My actual data set is a lot longer than this and contains a lot more data that needs to be expressed, so some way to condense the data and use a slicer is necessary. For example, I want to filter for Robert, see his average sales for his dogs sold and that he's planning on breeding two more dogs in the coming year.
Essentially, I need a better-looking version of this

Because my data sets are different in length and point to different fields, I can't simply combine the tables and create a large pivot out of it. Inputting dummy rows put them all in the same table would skew calculations for analysis downward, and I need a dynamic table that can search and update on-the-fly, so hard-coding calculations is out of the picture as well.
I tried my hand at PowerPivot, but it hasn't worked for me. Using a dummy table doesn't get the outputs I need because the only related column is the name of the Breeders and they point to different data sets and lengths.
Some advice on if this is doable using Excel or PowerPivot would be nice. If not, is there any way I can integrate these tables into a pivot for easy readability?

Please create a desired output that derives from your give input. As is, there is information in your output table that does not exist in your input tables.
